# Why I get Access Denied Error using WMI Connection?

Tags: c#, wmi, dcom

this is a similar error all around the internet but I am not able to reason out why this can happen in my case. I am trying to use WMI for remotely installing windwos services from my XP client machine. I use,

```
    ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
    options.EnablePrivileges = true;
    options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    options.Username = "domainName\userName";
    options.Password = "pwd";
    string path = string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", machineName);
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
    scope.Connect();
```

I get **'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005)'** error. I use a windows XP SP3 and trying to connect to windows server 2003.

I found out these but I did check all of these:

1. User account not admin - The user account is a local admin. I can use the same account, to do a instalutil and create services in that machine. This is the account underwhich my application services run.
2. dcomcnfg and check Enable DCOM - This is already enabled.
3. Changed Enabled Previliges and Impersonation properties in ConnectionOptions. But this doesnt help.
4. Firewall settings - The error message number doesnt say this. But, the machine is withing the same domain as the XP client.

Comment: On which line do you get the 'Access is denied' error message? On the scope.Connect() line?

Comment: Is your Windows Server 2003 joined to a domain? Is the user account a domain account or a local account on the Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Have added an answer for this which made it work for me. Thank you Hans for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The account that I used to login remotely (via mstsc) and install/uninstall services was NOT a local admin account. It was surprising because, I used the same account to install services in that machines, so assumed it would be a local admin. When I added the account to local admin, the WMI connectivity also worked. Hence, for remotely connecting to the machine, u need to use a local admin account.